# How do you set monaco-editor from readonly to writeable?

Tags: javascript, typescript, monaco-editor

In my code I created an editor like so:

```
this.monacoEditor = monaco.editor
  .create(
    document.getElementById('ide'), {
      model: null,
      readOnly: true,
      contextmenu: false,
    }
  );
```

So now that editor is readonly. How would I change `this.monacoEditor` to be writable/editable?

Answer (score 13):

I figured it out. In the context of the code above:

```
this.monacoEditor.updateOptions({readOnly: false});
```